# Why is torsion (curvature) a tensor field?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors

As I learned, for a differential manifold with an affine connection $(M,\nabla)$, its torsion is defined as
$$\begin{aligned}
  T:\mathscr{X}(M)\times \mathscr{X}(M) &\rightarrow \mathscr{X}(M)\\
  (X,Y) &\mapsto T(X,Y):= \nabla_XY-\nabla_Y X-[X,Y]
\end{aligned} $$
And I can check the multi-linearity.

My question is: Is $T$ a $(1,2)$ tensor (or tensor field)? I have learned that a (r,s) tensor field on $M$ is a smooth section of $T^{(r,s)}(M)$, mapping every $p\in M$ to a $(r,s)$ tensor over $T_p(M)$. But $T$ is defined globally, i.e. we cannot talk about $\nabla_{X_p}Y_p-\nabla_{Y_p} X_p-[X_p,Y_p]$.

So what does it exactly mean by saying $T$ a $(1,2)$ tensor? Are they equivalent definitions? Any comments or references are welcomed. THANKS!

Comment: google **tensor (field) characterization lemma** (or search on the site). This has been answered several times. Torsion and curvature are tensor **fields**.

Comment: You need to careful not to confuse $\frac {df}{dx} \Big|_p$ and $\frac d{dx}f(p)$. The value of the entire expression depends just on values at $p$, but the individual terms most assuredly do not.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks a lot! I see.